# I want to disable button if element contains class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable button if element contains class and I am trying to do it, but nothing works for me. please help me thanks

```js
$(function() {
 if ($('div').hasClass('exceeded-size')) {
    $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
 } else {
    $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container" data-image-index="0" id="mup-image-0" data-acceptable-image="0">
  <div class="image-size"> 3.1 MB </div>
  <div class="exceeded-size"> greater than 1 MB </div>
  <img src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/20bd149e-3368-4167-9b4b-a2719504a5ad" class="image-preview" alt="">
</div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary  w-100">Save</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: You have no *Button* to start with...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of converting your posted code into a runnable Stack Snippet, and included jQuery 3.3.1 (please correct to whichever version you're using). But, as Roko notes, you have `<button>` element, nor any element with `id="btnSubmit"`.

Comment: The `$('i')` selector  is not specific enough. It just takes for your website to have an other `<i>` element and you can watch your logic fail. Also, where's that `<i>` Element in your code?

Comment: okay roko what we need to put here ?

Comment: @MalikZubairMukhtar I would suggest an ID. IDs are unique (multiple IDs are not valid in a document). `<i>` can be anything. You did not explained that should `$("i")` be. Set and ID to that element in HTML and use that selector in JS And see my comment under Viktor's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('i').hasClass('exceeded-size')) {
  $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
} else {
  $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: Why not just: `$('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', $('#moreSpecific').hasClass('exceeded-size'))`